# To find inverse of $f$ ( using calculus)

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [–1,1] \to [–1,1]$ defined by $f(x) = x|x|$ ,find $f^{–1}(x)$

$f(x)= x|x|$

$y = x^2 , x>0$

$x = ±√y$

And

$f(x) = –x^2 , x<0$

$x = ±√(-y)$

It seems like inverse of $f$ doesn't exist, since, we are getting two values of $x$ ,which is in domain of $f^{–1}$

Graphically, the function comes out to be bijective. So inverse should exist.

What is wrong with the calculus I used to find the inverse of $f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $y \ge 0$, $f^{-1}(y) = +\sqrt{y}$, not $-\sqrt{y}$, because you want $x \ge 0$.
Similarly, if $y < 0$, $f^{-1}(y) = -\sqrt{-y}$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x>0$, $y>0$ also, so the right half is just
$$x=+\sqrt y$$
while the left is just
$$x=-\sqrt{-y}$$
which is a bijective function from $[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$

(We can stick 0 into either half, it doesn’t change anything either way)